# Building an older version of the webkit source?

Tags: svn, webkit

So I have grabbed a copy of the latest webkit svn and managed to debug/build it. However, I now want to debug a version a little older. Is there any way to download a copy of the source of an old webkit version? I can't find it anywhere =(.

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First browse it to see all versions available:
    http://svn.webkit.org/repository/webkit/releases/WebKitGTK

And then checkout the one you need, eg:
    svn co http://svn.webkit.org/repository/webkit/releases/WebKitGTK/webkit-1.4.1